# Google CloudLogging with service account - PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to send logs from my Node.js app to GCP CloudLogging. I'm using [nodejs-logging-bunyan](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan). I followed the [auth setup guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for a service account.

I can see the file being loaded. The following command

```
  console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
```

yields the name of the service-account's auth-credentials `json` file. But when running the logger, I get the following error from the lib:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
    ...
Emitted 'error' event on LoggingBunyan instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 7,
  details: 'The caller does not have permission',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

Furthermore, I use the same service account app credentials for accessing the SecretManager. Which proves to me that the app credentials are loaded correctly. So, this makes me think that I just need to add *the proper permissions* to the service account.

But I could not find anywhere in the documentation a mention of adding "logging permissions" to the service account. The only role they give [as example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) is `owner/editor`, but that's way too high.

Any idea what am I missing? And if it's just the right permissions to the service acc, then what are they?

Comment: Which roles have you already granted to your service account?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, your comment led me to the solution. I had to add the proper permission for the service-account role: `logging.logEntries.create` . The issue was that when I was setting up the role initially, I tried to search for "Cloud Logging" in the list of roles and nothing relevant came up. Now I searched for just "Logs" and the proper role came out. Now it's working.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer to make it more visible for other community members?

Comment: Did that literally a few sec before you commented! :D :D 
Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the proper permission for the service-account role: `logging.logEntries.create`.
The issue was that the documentation doesn't mention the need for setting up permissions in order to write to the logs.

Furthermore, when I was setting up the role initially, I tried to search for "Cloud Logging" in the list of roles and nothing relevant came up.

Then I searched for just "Logs" and the proper role group (`Logs Writer`) came out.

Comment: Cloud Logging previously was called Stackdriver. Things are being renamed. This guide will help you set the correct roles: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control